# Assign a drive letter to a Solaris disk in a Windows box

Tags: windows, share, ufs

I need some way to map a UFS Solaris drive (ie, assign a drive letter to it) while it is in a Windows XP box.

I've found utilities that will let me transfer files from a Solaris disk to a NTFS disk on the Windows box, but nothing that will let me map/share that Solaris disk.

And no, putting the Solaris disk in a Solaris box and using something like Samba to share the disk is unfortunately not an option.

Cat

Comment: If the disk is in a Windows system to be accessed by a Windows system...can't the data just be copied off to a disk that is NTFS and used from there?

Comment: I have a utility (UFS Explorer) that copies files from a UFS Solaris formatted disk in a Windows machine to another drive in the Windows machine.  It takes approx. 11 hours to strip a 1 TB SATA drive this way, and I have 70+ disks.  And then all those files need to be processed.  So yes, I can just copy the files, but that adds weeks to the data processing time.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to assign a drive letter in Windows as it it not a supported file system.  The recovery utilities should be able to access the drive directly using the disk and partition number.

Answer (score 0):

There was only one tool I could find for manipulating UFS filesystems from Windows...
[UFS2tools](http://ufs2tools.sourceforge.net/)

Only other thing I could think of would be using VMWare to create an OpenSolaris or BSD system that could read UFS and try mounting the disk from that then sharing it out as SAMBA from that system. Lots of overhead, but I don't know what exactly your longterm goals are or what exactly you're trying to achieve beyond getting data off the disk unless you're just sharing the data on it, period, in which case I'm still lost why it has to stay on a UFS formatted drive on a server not meant for reading it...?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying not to get too long winded. :-) If you see my comment to Bart's post, you'll see why using something like UFStools is too time intensive (ie $$$).  If I can't come up with a better solution, I will indeed just keep the drives in a Solaris box and use Samba to get to the files.  However there is a *huge* Windows-only cultural push in the data processing lab where all of this will reside, and I think they're afraid of having a Solaris box in there.  Plus, it does require an additional computer.

Answer (score 0):

How about VMWare a box into Open Solaris (or Linux) to NFS or Samba export the disk to another VMWare partition on the same hardware running Windows?  You should get some fast transfer, you don't need additional hardware, and you'll at least be trying to let the Windows-only crowd feel OK.